# Find array with the closest values to a given array from a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, computer-vision

I have a list of 2-D numpy arrays. These arrays are image histograms. These arrays each produce a different histogram curve when plotted with matplotlib.

For ex:

```
arrayList = [arr1,arr2,arr3,........arr(n)]
```

I have another 2-D array:

```
targetArray = [[1][2][3]........[n]]
```

I want to grab the array from the arrayList that looks closest to the targetArray when plotted.
How can I achieve this?

[image: This is an example of what each array looks like when plotted.]

Each array in that list has a unique histogram.

Comment: I think you will need to be more specific about what exactly "looks closest" means.

Comment: what is "looks closest" and can you provide actual example of how you might calculate it with a very small image?

Comment: @fishstix44 Let's suppose an S-bend curve. The target array produces an S-bend curve on the plot. I want to grab the array that produces a curve closest to that S-bend curve. I hope I'm able to clarify.

Comment: @MarkM Please take a look at the edited question

Answer (score 2):

If I read correctly you want to find the arrays with closest distribution

This reminds me the [Kullback-Liebler Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)

If you fix the bins of your histograms and normalize it to have sum 1, then you will have an approximation of the probability density function.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to calculate the sum of the absolute value differences of each of the points. Run the following code:

```py
total_diff = 0
for x in range(len(arrayList):
    first_el = arrayList[x][0]
    second_el = targetArray[x][0]
    total_diff += numpy.abs(first_el - second_el)

print(total_diff)
```